# getVariantManager error with DexProtector

Tags: android, gradle, upgrade, dexprotector

After I update the classpath to 4.2.1 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1'

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to request a new version of DexProtector's Gradle plugin from Licel.